# Can I use JPA @Query annotation to call a simple Postgres function?

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have a postgres function which accepts the first name as input and returns last name as output. I need to implement a spring boot application which uses @Query annotation to call the function.

Sample:-

```
(@Query(value = "select * from get_name(first_name,last_name)", nativeQuery=true) .
```

I have created the CRUD repository for this and want to know the remaining java classes required to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should work.

You say your function accepts the firstName as parameter and returns the lastName:

```
@Query(value = "select * from get_name(:firstName)", nativeQuery=true)
String getName(String firstName);
```